# How to level a paella

Tags: food

A paella is just a big pan, used tipically in spanish dishes (it is also the name of one of the dishes, but that is beyond the point). It looks like this:

[image]

The dishes prepared there are usually very shallow, and the water is absorbed by the rice/pasta, so if it is not completelly level, the higher parts will stop being cooked before the rest. So we need to make sure it is perfectly level.

Is there any way to make sure the paella is perfectly horizontal and if not, is there any way to incline it so it is horizontal? Note: as we will be eating from it, any solution that needs to get the paella away for washing are not good, as whatever we did to get it level (usually puting small rocks or paper under the holder's legs will get wrecked with the moving)

Comment: I just realized the image is way too big, but I cannot find a way to resize it. Can anybody more knowledgeable than me help me?

Comment: Done - have a look at the edit to see how it's done [you still need to upload it the regular way, then tweak back to regular html code] ...& I just realised I don't yet have the rep here for it to go through without peer review... so eventually... you'll get to see it ;-)

Comment: Thanks, just accepted it! It still takes way too much vertical space, but that is because of the image i uploaded

Comment: Photoshop to the rescue [still needs peer review before it will be seen]

Answer (score 1):

To check if the pan is level, place it on a surface you know is horizontal and use a spirit level. Or pour some water into the pan, and measure the water level at different locations using a ruler. If at one location the water level is higher, the pan is not level.

Then you have to check if your cooking range is level. Again, use a spirit level. If the range is not level, adjust it (generally, a range has adjustable feet).

If you have a gas range, you have to check the level of the range itself, but also the cast-iron frames where you place your pans. If the frame is bent, you have to wrap some sheet metal (preferably iron) around the prongs to shim the prong to the correct height.

For other ranges (e.g. electric and induction): **never** use shims between the hot plate and the pan. Adjust the feet of the range instead.

Comment: A few drops of water will also tell you if the pan is level. Water will seek the lowest level. A few metal washers can be put under the low part of the pan supports (the grate) over a gas stove burner to level it individually. They can also be used under electric burner elements to level each one. You may not have to level the whole appliance for one burner.